# C# How to make Dictionary<Type,Generic<Type>>?

Tags: c#, dictionary, generics, types

I would like to make dictionary which stores different Types and generic class which uses this Type. How can I do such thing so each entry can be other type and get corresponding generic class as value?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why don't use just generics itself?

Comment: Well, `class<int>` is a different type than `class<string>`, so unless your generic classes implements a non-generic interface, what's going to be a problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get it. Do you speak about something like Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>?

Comment: `CustomType<T> : Dictionary<T, SomeGenericType<T>>`?

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary<Type, dynamic> generics = new Dictionary<Type, dynamic>()
{
    {typeof(string), new List<string>() {"test"}},
    {typeof(int), new List<int>(){ 0 }}
};
foreach (Type genericsKey in generics.Keys)
{
    foreach (dynamic element in generics[genericsKey])
        Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

Output:

> test
>   0

Comment: How can Add to this dictionary on runtime?

Comment: @ArekŻyłkowski Using `generics.Add(...)`, like with any other dictionary too.